# Fetch data from Firebase Realtime Database based on a parameter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a requirement where I want to fetch the data from Firebase Realtime Database based on a parameter. For example my Firebase Realtime Database has users and posts and friends list and if I want to get the friends posts by sending the user id value to fire base.Can someone please help .? Any help appreciable.

```
  mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange():" + dataSnapshot.toString());
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read Bullet list.", error.toException());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You'll need to use a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for that. For more concrete help, add the a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) you are trying to query to your question. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure.